# jquery - Disable / Simulate "enter" behavior for submit button

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

EDIT **
To try to make this a little clearer....

When I click the input put button with the mouse, it posts via ajax, like I want it to: mysite.com:8888/save/1?val=&val2=&val3=...

When I'm in a textfield and I hit "enter", it submits to itself, not via ajax... It just works like a regular submission form... I'm just trying to figure out how to get the "enter" button to post via ajax as well...

This is the (partial) html for the form:

```
<legend>Add Directory Entry</legend>
<div id="statusmessage"></div>
<div class="form-radios clearfix">
    <label class="option" for="edit-type-0"><input id="edit-type-0" name="type" value="0" class="form-radio clearfix" type="radio"> option1</label>

    <label class="option" for="edit-type-1">
    <input id="edit-type-1" name="type" value="1" class="form-radio clearfix" type="radio"> option2 </label>

    <label class="option" for="edit-type-2">
    <input id="edit-type-2" name="type" value="2" class="form-radio clearfix" type="radio"> option3 </label>

    <label class="option" for="edit-type-3">
    <input id="edit-type-3" name="type" value="3" class="form-radio clearfix" type="radio"> option4 </label>
</div>

<label for="edit-name">Name: <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
<input maxlength="128" name="name" id="edit-name" size="60" value="" class="form-text required" type="text">

<label for="edit-phone">Phone: </label>
<input maxlength="128" name="phone" id="edit-phone" size="60" value="" class="form-text" type="text">

<input name="op" id="edit-save" value="Save Entry" class="form-submit ahah-processed" type="submit">
```

The php for the creation of the submit button is:

```
$form['addentry']['save'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Save Entry'),
        '#submit' => array(),
        '#ahah' => array(
            'path' => 'family/'.$user->uid.'/savenewentry',
            'wrapper' => 'ahah-example-new-row-wrapper',
            'method' => 'prepend',
            'effect' => 'fade',
            'progress' => array('type' => 'bar', 'message' => t('Please wait...')),
        ),
    );
```

So, when I click the button, I get the progress indication, etc., when I hit "enter" the whole page is submitted and it refreshes...

---

I have an ajax form that uses a submit button (has to be input type="submit"... can't use "button").  When I click on it, it works as expected in that it doesn't actually "submit" information, but when I hit enter, it submits the form entirely.  I've been looking through the forums here, and I can find lots of posts that talk about disabling the behavior, but I want it to work as though "clicking" the button and hitting the enter key work exactly the same... I tried various iterations that were posted in some of the other threads (lots with "preventDefault"), but it keeps submitting it on enter...

```
/*
There are a lot more fields, but if, for example, you're in the 
zip code text field and hit enter, the form will "submit".  
If you click enter, it posts and responds as expected... 
*/
<input type="text" value="" id="edit-zip" name="zip" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="edit-save" name="op">
```

I tried this:

```
  $('form#my-custom-form input#edit-save').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input#edit-save').click();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, hitting enter when any form element has focus can cause the form's submit event to fire.

```
$('form#my-custom-form').submit(...your handler function here...)
```

so handle this event in the same way you handle the button

Comment: maybe I didn't explain it well...  There is only one submit button.  There is no handler for it. But, clicking on the button behaves differently than when hitting 'enter'

Comment: I'm confused - how is the submit button behaving when clicked? In your example above, you've attached a keypress handler to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the `preventDefault(`) to your submit buttons `click` event, bind it to your form's `submit` event.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Tried that as well... also tried with just return false, but it still doesn't work

Comment: You stated "When I click on it, it works as expected in that it doesn't actually "submit" information", how exactly is it preventing the form from submitting the data then, when you click the submit?

Comment: When I click the input put button with the mouse, it posts via ajax: http://mysite.com:8888/save/1?val=&val2=&val3=... When I hit "enter", it submits to itself, not via ajax... It just works like a regular submission form...  I'm just trying to figure out how to get the "enter" button to post via ajax as well...

Answer (score 0):

You problem is similar to this:
[event.preventDefault() not working in Mozilla or IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486440/event-preventdefault-not-working-in-mozilla-or-ie?answertab=active#tab-top)

And heres your solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14486639/1949475