# HTML form continues to submit before JQuery Dialog selection is made?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in HTML:

```
<form id="notes" method="post" onsubmit="return notes_validate()">
```

In this form I've included a JQuery Dialog box (I've connect the scripts and it's working):

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Alert" style="display:none;">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Continue and submit?</p>
</div>
```

I have a JavaScript script called "notes_validate()" that validates elements on the form and returns true if all elements pass the checks.

In this script, as one of the final validation steps, I prompt the user with this JQuery Dialog box; I'm trying to get the Dialog box to submit the form if "Yes" is selected and return false (don't submit the form) if "Cancel" is selected.

In "notes_validate()" is:

```
if(validated){

        $(function() {
            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height:240,
                width:300,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        return true;
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    }
```

The issue is that the form is automatically submitting before any option is selected. I also have a submit button in the form in HTML:

```
<input class="submit" style="float:left" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

What's the issue(s)?

Comment: I might be wrong but maybe you need `preventdefault()` somewhere ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting

Comment: change input type to button instead on submit

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of asynchronous javascript. Your return true and return false cannot affect the outcome of the form's submit event where they are located.

Comment: I wrote an answer over here that will solve your problem, simply replace the ajax request with your dialog. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14486639/400654

Comment: the functions that handle `yes` & `cancel` return either true or false but those return values need to be passed to the parent function do they not to so that the parent function itself returns either true ( form will submit ) or false ( the form will not submit )?

Comment: @RamRaider the problem is the parent function has to return before those callbacks can run, therefore the parent function can't possibly return what those callbacks do.

Comment: not being proficient with jQuery and not seeing the entire function doesn't help but the parent function needs to return either true or false for the method it is invoked does it not?

Comment: yes, and it's simply not possible. :) so another approach has to be taken. It's like trying to eat your pizza before it is delivered.

Comment: you mention asynchronous javascript which implies ajax but I see nothing that suggests ajax. But then - not being proficient with jquery I might well have missed the point of that

Comment: The dialog is asynchronous. You open a dialog, then at some point later, the user will click ok or cancel, thus triggering the callback asynchronously. The parent function cant wait for that click to occur, because the click can't happen until after the parent function returns.

Comment: :) I gotcha ~ I see now what you are driving at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're expecting `onsubmit="return notes_validate()"` to keep the form from submitting, but your threading is messed up.  You're not returning anything directly from `notes_validate()`.

Once you hit `$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({...})`, that's a different "thread".  Your `notes_validate` method is continuing on as if nothing happened.

What you need is

```
function notes_validate(event) {
    if(validated){
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:240,
            width:300,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    $( "#notes" ).submit();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Update:
As pointed out, it would be better to remove the `onsubmit` portion of this altogether.  Changing your button to the following after removing the `onsubmit` from your form should do the trick:

```
<input class="submit" style="float:left" type="button" onclick="notes_validate()" />
```

Comment: there's one minor flaw here. by using `$( "#notes" ).submit();`, you will re-trigger the submit event possibly causing an infinite loop. You should instead submit the form without triggering the event. `$("#notes")[0].submit();`

Comment: Good point, would be better to trigger this on button click.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I would also add that when I added multiple dialog boxes, they weren't working until I added this line to each of the Cancel functions: $( this ).dialog( "destroy" );